# How to ignore key press events that don't output characters

Tags: qt

I'm developing a virtual musical keyboard that allows you to press keys on your keyboard and have it play notes. So in my MainWindow class I have reimplemented keyPressEvent. I would like to ignore events generated by modifiers (Control, Alt, Shift, etc.), as well as events generated by other non-character keys such as Tab, Backspace, and Enter. Something like this would be ideal:

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if (!event->key().isCharacter()))
    {
        event->ignore();
        return;
    }

    // handle the event
}
```

Is there a way to do something like that (short of testing every possible non-character key individually)? If not, is there at least a way to easily ignore the event if it is a modifier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you want `QKeyEvent::text()`.

Comment: Perfect... I can just check the size of the returned QString, and ignore the event if it equals 0. Thanks.

Comment: Anthony: `isEmpty()` is generally preferred to checking `size()`.

Comment: Strangely, in my app, when I am trying this, it prints out the letter correctly each time I type something, except for the letters W, A, S and D. In these four cases the code doesn't even enter the overridden `keyPressEvent()` method!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is unfortunately incomplete. If you press `Ctrl+C`, then `QKeyEvent::text()` will return `"\x03"` (^C "End of Text").
That is not an empty string.

I decided to look inside the Qt source code, since they need to handle this problem for `QLineEdit` as well:

- In `QLineEdit::keyPressEvent`:

  ```cpp
  d->control->processKeyEvent(event);
  ```

  [src/widgets/widgets/qlineedit.cpp:1742](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/7689d4ad2f673317af432aae498da74d13703126/src/widgets/widgets/qlineedit.cpp#L1742)
- In `QWidgetLineControl::processKeyEvent`:

  ```cpp
  if (unknown
      && !isReadOnly()
      && isAcceptableInput(event)) {
      insert(event->text());
  ```

  [src/widgets/widgets/qwidgetlinecontrol.cpp:1912](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/7689d4ad2f673317af432aae498da74d13703126/src/widgets/widgets/qwidgetlinecontrol.cpp#L1912-L1915)
- In `QInputControl::isAcceptableInput`:

  ```cpp
  bool QInputControl::isAcceptableInput(const QKeyEvent *event) const
  {
      const QString text = event->text();
      if (text.isEmpty())
          return false;

      const QChar c = text.at(0);

      // Formatting characters such as ZWNJ, ZWJ, RLM, etc. This needs to go before the
      // next test, since CTRL+SHIFT is sometimes used to input it on Windows.
      if (c.category() == QChar::Other_Format)
          return true;

      // QTBUG-35734: ignore Ctrl/Ctrl+Shift; accept only AltGr (Alt+Ctrl) on German keyboards
      if (event->modifiers() == Qt::ControlModifier
              || event->modifiers() == (Qt::ShiftModifier | Qt::ControlModifier)) {
          return false;
      }

      if (c.isPrint())
          return true;

      if (c.category() == QChar::Other_PrivateUse)
          return true;

      if (c.isHighSurrogate() && text.size() > 1 && text.at(1).isLowSurrogate())
          return true;

      if (m_type == TextEdit && c == u'\t')
          return true;

      return false;
  }
  ```

  [src/gui/text/qinputcontrol.cpp:21](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/7689d4ad2f673317af432aae498da74d13703126/src/gui/text/qinputcontrol.cpp#L21-L53)

This is exactly what you need but you may want to change the check for `\t` and ignore that as well.